# On development server , I am detach one db and attach to other drive from that day , log size increasing exponentially?

Tags: sql-server

On development  server , i am detach one db and attach to other drive  from that day , log size increasing exponentially,  when we detach db and attach to other drive any setting will change  ? because after every 2-3 day log size increases up to disk size full , Please advise me?   Thank in advance

Comment: What is the recovery model ? You are probably on `Full Recovery`. You may want to switch to simple recovery model. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: as above said, check FULL/BULK/SIMPLE recovery model. If FULL/BULK are needed, remember to setup LOG backup jobs

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually i want point in time recovery so choose full recovery mode , but before detach and attach i am not facing this issue , so want help regarding this